# Automatically set focus to first cell of UITableView when view loads

Tags: swift, uitableview, tvos

I have been trying to make an application where when the view loads, the focus automatically goes to first cell of UITableview.

I have tried using the UIFocusGuide and then in `prefferedFocusView()` method return the tableView but that did not work.

I then wrote this code

```
 var viewToFocus: UIView? = nil {
    didSet {
        if viewToFocus != nil {
            print("called1 ")
            self.setNeedsFocusUpdate();
            self.updateFocusIfNeeded();
        }
    }
}

override weak var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    if viewToFocus != nil {
        print("called2 ")

        return viewToFocus;
    } else {
        return super.preferredFocusedView;
    }
}
```

In view did load

```
        self.viewToFocus = myTableView
```

But that did not work as well.

Comment: Does the view only contains a table view? Or it contains other views too?

Comment: @Mr.UB yes, it has collectionview as well.. I am populating colllectionview when user focus on item in uitableview. so by default, the first cell should be focused in tableview!!!

Comment: When you say `prefferedFocusView`, did you mean `preferredFocusedView`?

Comment: Please [read the whole of this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) about adding urgent begging to questions.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to get this by setting `tableView.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true` in `viewDidLoad`, then I implemented the delegate method for preferred focus:

```
func indexPathForPreferredFocusedView(in tableView: UITableView) -> IndexPath? {
   return NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)
}
```

When `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath` - `If YES, when focusing on a table view the last focused index path is focused automatically. If the table view has never been focused, then the preferred focused index path is used.`

**Swift 5**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    myTableView.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true
}
```

and then in your delegate

```
func indexPathForPreferredFocusedView(in tableView: UITableView) -> IndexPath? {
    return IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as it seems this do not work when `tableView.reloadData()` being called.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code snippet to the implementation of the ViewController class with the tableview delegate invoked:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    return true
}
return false
}
```

Comment: This will allow him to focus all items except the first item!

Answer (score 0):

In tableView:WillDisplayCell method add below code

```
 [cell setSelected:YES animated:NO];
```

for first cell

Answer (score 0):

You can set the scroll position automatically to go to the top cell.

```
let topCell:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(topCell, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None, animated: true)
```

I am not sure if this is the same behaviour as `preferredFocusedView`though.

Comment: @Saty my apologies I never noticed it was for tvos. Hope you get it sorted

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UITableView {

    func scrollToTop(section: Int) {
        let rows = self.numberOfRows(inSection: section)

        if rows > 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rows - 1, section: section)
                self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if there is only one section replace section with 0